# How to disable automatic building of localized resource DLLs when embedded resource name contains culture substring?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

I noticed a peculiar problem when I try to include a file as an `EmbeddedResource` in my project.

If the file contains a culture name substring (e.g. `test.en.json`), the C# compiler will completely ignore the `EmbeddedResource` directive from my project file and instead generate an external localization file (a satelite assembly, I believe), named `MyProject.Resources.dll` and output it in a subfolder called `en`.

This is most definitely not what I want! How can I persuade the compiler to just do the usual thing it would normally do, if the file name was different (e.g. `test.json`)?

Simply renaming my resource files to avoid such coincidences is not something I'd be happy with, because it has other side effects.

**UPDATE**

Maybe I wasn't clear enough... The reason I don't want any of this magic is because I'm going for a single executable application. Additional DLLs in a subfolder, even if *automagically* loaded, defeat my intended purpose. I just want the normal (i.e. no localization-related helpfulness) embedded resource behavior.

Comment: Please, share [mcve]

Comment: I misunderstood the problem at first, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27272085/1997232) is someone having similar issue.

Comment: @Sinatr: Thx. But let me just say, wow! It looks incredibly involved for such a simple little unwanted thing. I'll have to study that answer a bit, first.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of item [How can I prevent embedded resource file culture being set based on its filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477616/how-can-i-prevent-embedded-resource-file-culture-being-set-based-on-its-filename)

Answer (score 2):

This problem kept me busy for a few hours.
I solved it with the attribute `WithCulture`.
In the C# project file (.csproj) this looks something like below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   ...
   <ItemGroup>
      ...
      <EmbeddedResource Include="test.en.json" WithCulture="false" />
      ...
      <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\**" WithCulture="false" />         
   <ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Looks promising! I'll test it in the near future and accept this answer if it works! How did you manage to find this?